# How to Submit Form from Outside?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a tabbed application setup as the following:

**Navigation.cshtml partial view**

```
<li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="TabOne" asp-action="TabOne">Tab One</a></li>
<li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="TabTwo" asp-action="TabTwo">Tab Two</a></li>
<li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="TabThree" asp-action="TabThree">Tab Three</a></li>
```

**TabOne.cshtml**

```
<form id="TabOne" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
    <!-- Fields here -->
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success pull-right">Save & Continue</button>
</form>
```

So on `Tab One`, if you click the `Save & Continue` button, the `TabOne` controller's POST method will fire and try to submit.

My question is, how can I fire the same `POST` method for `TabOne` when I click on either the `Tab Two` or `Tab Three` link in my Navigation partial view and then redirect to the clicked tab?

Comment: Is this Bootstrap [tab](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs)?

Comment: @Win - No, I'm just using a Bootstrap Navbar for my tabs.

Answer (score 0):

If these POSTs are being passed into a Controller class, then it's quite easy. I noticed each of these "Tabs" is associated with a different Controller and Action. I'm assuming that is intentional for my answer below. If not, I will edit it to reflect your structure.

In your TabOneController.cs, you should have two entries for the "TabOne" view type; a regular HttpGet and an HttpPost. Modify the HttpPost to look like:

```
[HttpPost, ActionName("TabOne")]
public async Task<IActionResult> TabOne() {
    // Do whatever tasks here to process the form data.
    return RedirectToAction("TabTwo", "TabTwoController");
}
```

Where "TabTwo" is the name of the Action and "TabTwoController" is the Controller name.

If you need to pass any data along to Tab Two, you can add route parameters by using:

```
return RedirectToAction("TabTwo", "TabTwoController", new { param = value, param2 = value2 });
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I'm still a little confused. So if I am on `Tab One` and I want to navigate to `Tab Three` by using my `<li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="TabThree" asp-action="TabThree">Tab Three</a></li>` tab link which is outside of `Tab One`'s `<form />` how exactly would I fire my `POST` for `Tab One`? Currently clicking on `Tab Three`'s link will only fire the `HttpGet` method for `Tab Three`. I want it to fire the `POST` method for whichever tab I'm on and then redirect to whichever Tab I clicked.